# Is there a way to ping a dynamic server using HOST NAME?

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way in vb.net to ping a server name programmatically? I mean many departments will use the program but has different servers.

For example different departments has one server. Accounting has their own while Treasury has their own. How or What should i use to ping their server name without directly putting their host names? Is there a way?

Comment: Load the names from a config file.

Comment: What if i don't have any names? I mean the program needs to search the names on its own.

Comment: A server at minimum has an IP address. You can generally put those in place of the hostname and expect things to work. It would also be extremely unusual at the network level for any host to not have a hostname of some kind.

Comment: I see. I'll try to make things possible with the IP's. And yeees they have, im just thinking that what "IF" i dont know their host names and ip adresses. Thank you! Godbless! :)

Comment: >`"What if I don't know their names and ip addresses."` Then you _ask_. :)

Comment: Oooooh i didn't saw that haha. My bad! Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: I have a follow up question, if you wouldn't mind? How can i check if my printers is shared on the network?  Using vb.net ofcourse.

Comment: I haven't used the printer APIs in .Net much. I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: I see. This is my limit for now i have to wait for 90mins again lool. The first question i have which still has no answers is how do i check the Network Discovery On/Off using .net. Please check my question out. Thanks!